# Generating a unique QR code for each Order in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, orders

Ok , i want to build a store that sale a various of products one of these is
courses training, every student choose one of a training courses as product and checkout after,in the order email we will find all the student's details with training courses detail(date ,place and trainer)the name of products that is buy and each order has a unique QR code that will be scanned and verify if the student has a order(exist or not) plz help me  ?

Comment: Please flesh out the information with an example scenario to get a grasp of what you want to achieve in a more concise manner. Maybe even doing that leads you to the answer you need. It seems this is not a simple and concise question. Probably you'll need multiple parts working together to make this work. Once you define more clearly your problem and design a possible solution, stackoverflow could help you with problems you encounter along the way

Comment: ok ,ELMesa i had add all the informations that you need to help me

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing anything of WooCommerce or Wordpress I would suggest:

1. Adding a 'Custom order metadata item' with a unique ID:

   - Check:'[Add custom order item meta data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004597/add-custom-order-item-meta-data)'
   - **Maybe this is unnecessary and you can reuse the plain ID from the order**
2. Then '[Dynamically generating a QR code with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943368/dynamically-generating-a-qr-code-with-php)' to render the QR

Comment: but how to add  this 'Dynamically generating a QR code with PHP' in my woocommerce ?

Comment: thanks , your solution is very helpful, first i want to ask you about the setting of {hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_add_order_item_meta} and where include it.
 ,actually i had integrate this "<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&choe=UTF-8" title="Link to Google.com" />
" and put it in order-details.php into the table the QR is shown in order_received and in order email also but in pdf invoice the QR code not shown !!! can you help me plz.

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't know much about PHP and anything about Woocomerce. Just thought of a generic solution and googled a pair of links to StackOverflow. I hope you manage to get that working. Good luck, mate.